# How to call Python pip in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

After upgrading pip i can't call pip in VSCode. If it's not 'pip' or 'pip3' then what is it?

```
PS C:\Users\dyhli\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Python\Python> pip install pandas
pip : 

The name "pip" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable.
the program being taken. Check the spelling of the name, as well as the presence and correct
path, then try again.
string:1 character:1

+ pip install pandas
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried calling 'pip', 'pip3' and 'pip22'

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the path of your pip installation to your PATH system variable.

By default, pip is installed to C:\Python34\Scripts\pip (pip now comes bundled with new versions of python), so the path "C:\Python34\Scripts" needs to be added to your PATH variable.

To check if it is already in your PATH variable, type echo %PATH% at the CMD prompt

To add the path of your pip installation to your PATH variable,
you can use the Control Panel or the setx command. For example:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts"
```